# Quickblox REST API Unexpected signature on Laravel

Tags: php, android, ios, rest, quickblox

I'm getting the following json response from QuickBlox REST API:

```
{
    "base": ["Unexpected signature"]
}
```

My signature method:

```
private function createSignature($login, $password, $timestamp, $nonce)
{
    $signatureContent = "application_id=" . env('QB_APP_ID') .
        "&auth_key=" . env('QB_APP_KEY') .
        "&nonce=" . $nonce .
        "&timestamp=" . $timestamp .
        "&user[login]=" . $login .
        "&user[password]=" . $password;

    return hash_hmac('sha1', $signatureContent, env('QB_APP_SECRET'));
}
```

The Application ID and Auth Key and  is correct. The `$signatureContent` value(break lines just to improve the text readability):

```
application_id=24544
&auth_key=6N9bYKT-fKGRQ7q
&nonce=268302610
&timestamp=1438287989
&user[login]=tester1@test.net
&user[password]=qwer1234
```

I getting this response when I try to create a session, using this params:

```
$postBody = http_build_query([
    'application_id' => env('QB_APP_ID'),
    'auth_key' => env('QB_APP_KEY'),
    'timestamp' => $ts, // SAME VALUE ON SIGNATURE: 1438287989
    'nonce' => $nonce, // SAME VALUE ON SIGNATURE: 268302610
    'signature' => $signature,
    'user[login]' => $login,
    'user[password]' => $password
]);

// cURL Request and Response....
```

What's wrong with my signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm creating a new user register, so aren't necessary user[login] and user[password] params. These params are required just to sign in.